# for display dynamic column names in jqgrid from server response how to write loadcomplete event with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

problem with dynamic column names in jqgrid getting blank grid with no column names and no data?
Getting bland grid nocolumn names and date in jqgrid here is my code i am unable to find the 
why am i getting blank grid i am using loadcoplete event and ajax call

Thanks in advance 
here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    jq(function() {
        jq("#grid").jqGrid({

    url:'<%= request.getContextPath() %>/admin/dataGrid',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['','','','','',
              '','','','','',
              '','','','','', 
              '','','','','',
              '','','','','',
              '','','','',''],
    colModel:[
        {name:'p1',index:'p1', width:55,align:"right",hidden: true ,formatter:'date', formatoptions: {srcformat:'ISOLong', newformat:'H:i:s'}},
        {name:'p2',index:'p2', width:55,align:"right",hidden: true  },
        {name:'p3',index:'p3', width:55,align:"right",hidden: true },
        {name:'p4',index:'p4', width:55,align:"right",hidden: true },
        {name:'p5',index:'p5', width:55,align:"right",hidden: true },
        {name:'p6',index:'p6', width:55,align:"right",hidden: true},
        {name:'p7',index:'p7', width:55,align:"right",hidden: true},        
        {name:'p8',index:'p8', width:55,align:"right",hidden: true},
        {name:'p9',index:'p9', width:55,align:"right",hidden: true},
        {name:'p10',index:'p10', width:55,align:"right",hidden: true},
        {name:'p11',index:'p11',width:55,align:"right",hidden: true},
        {name:'p12',index:'p12',width:55,align:"right", hidden: true},
        {name:'p13',index:'p13',width:55,align:"right", hidden: true},
        {name:'p14',index:'p14',width:55,align:"right",hidden: true},   
        {name:'p15',index:'p15', width:55,align:"right",hidden: true},
        {name:'p16',index:'p16', width:55,align:"right",hidden: true},
        {name:'p17',index:'p17', width:55,align:"right",hidden: true},
        {name:'p18',index:'p18', width:55,align:"right",hidden: true},
        {name:'p19',index:'p19', width:55,align:"right",hidden: true},
        {name:'p20',index:'p20', width:55,align:"right",hidden: true},      
        {name:'p21',index:'p21', width:55,align:"right",hidden: true},      
        {name:'p22',index:'p22', width:55,align:"right",hidden: true},
        {name:'p23',index:'p23',width:55,align:"right",hidden: true},
        {name:'p24',index:'p24',width:55,align:"right", hidden: true},
        {name:'p25',index:'p25',width:55,align:"right", hidden: true},
        {name:'p26',index:'p26',width:55,align:"right",hidden: true},
        {name:'p27',index:'p27',width:55,align:"right",hidden: true},
        {name:'p28',index:'p28',width:55,align:"right", hidden: true},
        {name:'p29',index:'p29',width:55,align:"right", hidden: true},
        {name:'p30',index:'p30',width:55,align:"right",hidden: true},   
    ],
    postData: { 
    },
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    height: 230,
    autowidth: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    pager: '#pager',
    viewrecords: true,
    emptyrecords: "Empty records",
    loadonce: false,
    viewrecords: true,
    caption:"Meter Data",
    footerrow: true,
    userDataOnFooter: true,
    loadComplete: function() {
         alert("load");
        /*   $ ("#grid").jqGrid('jq',{datatype:'json'}); */
    },
    jsonReader : {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "totalPages",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        cell: "cell",
        userdata    : "userdata"

    },
  json : function(jsondata){

        $.ajax({
            url : '<%= request.getContextPath() %>/admin/dataGrid',
            data : jsondata,
            dataType :"json",
            complete: function(jsondata,stat)
            {
                if(stat=="success"){
                    var thegrid = jQuery("#grid")[0];
                    thegrid.addJSONData(eval("("+jsondata.responseText+")"))
                }
            }
        })
    } 
}); 

jq("#grid").jqGrid("setLable",23,"Column23");
jq("#grid").jqGrid("showCol",23); 
        jq("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
                {edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:true},
                { },
                { },
                { }, 
                { 
                    sopt:['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt', 'cn', 'bw', 'ew'],
                    closeOnEscape: true, 
                     }
        );
});


</script>
```